# How do I define the class for isinstance()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a function that affects only items in a certain class. This happens within the Python API - intro [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html)

Currently I do

```
def tidy_names(l):
    for k in l.keys():
        print(k, type(l[k]))
        
tidy_names(locals())
```

which outputs (for example)

```
parte_B1 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_B2 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_B3 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_B4 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_G1 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_G2 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
parte_C1 <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
```

what Id like to do is

```
def tidy_names(l):
    for k in l.keys():
        if isinstance(l[k], some_class):
            l[k].name = k
```

where some class points to `<class 'bpy_types.Object'>`  - trying

```
isinstance(l[k], "<class 'bpy_types.Object'>"))
```

throws an error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

So the question is: what do I need to pass to `isinstance()` so it works like I'd like it to?

Comment: Try using the actual class, not a single instance of it... `import bpy_types; isinstance(foo, bpy_types.Object)` otherwise, you wouldn't want `isinstance`, you'd want `==`

Comment: You'll need to get the actual class object, as you do with `type(l[k])`, not just a string of its `__repr__` output.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thanks - but ```isinstance(l[k], bpy_types.Object))``` throws ```NameError: name 'bpy_types' is not defined``` - even if I do ```import bpy_types```

Comment: Well, I don't know where that module comes from, but I assumed you had a `bpy_types.py` file of your own

Comment: You can do `if 'bpy_types.Object' in str(type(...))`as a workaround if you can't get the right import

Comment: @OneCricketeer - it's from the Blender Python API - I edited the question to clarify. Maybe I'm bette off heading to blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't see an edit, but yes, it'd be great if you could how the l list was populated

Comment: @OneCricketeer - sorry, it got lost. Re-did it. In the meantime I've used the ```str(type(...))``` workaround - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't confuse the type bound to a name (`int`) with the string returned by `type.__repr__` (`"<class 'int'>"`) `isinstance` requires the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want the following

```
from bpy import types as bpy_types

print(isinstance(list_element, bpy_types.Object))
```

Comment: Documentation link: [`bpy.types.Object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this instead.

```
isinstance(l[k], bpy_types.Object))
```

Example usage to check if an object is an integer (or sub class of an integer) is

```
isinstance(1, int)
```

Comment: thanks - but ```isinstance(l[k], bpy_types.Object))``` throws ```NameError: name 'bpy_types' is not defined``` - even if I do ```import bpy_types```

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: I did a quick google search on bpy_types and found this link. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html

Maybe you can try bpy.types.Object